# Git Pull Requests are Failing

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, git-commit, pull-request

I started working on github and made a few changes to public repositories and submitted the pull requests.

I always get a red cross around my pull requests and it says that:

> All checks have failed

This is happening to me on **every repository**, the build tests or continuous-integration fails even though I **just made changes to ReadMe** of the public repository.

Please help as this just blocks any of my contributions.

Comment: Is there occurring `conflicts` when you are trying to create pull request? Pull master branch into your branch & make sure there are no conflicts.

Comment: @sajibkhan no conflicts are there...it says continuous integration is failing...erverytime

Comment: Do you see what the error is for CI? When you creating a pull req, CI build is getting failed (possibly `tests` failed or else).

Comment: If these are public, you should be linking them.

Comment: @Pockets Hi, plz explain a bit more: m I missing any step?. I have several pull requests failed due to this and nobody in my college so far has given a solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm saying that if these are public repos, you should be adding links to them here so that we can see them.

Comment: I am getting "Deploy preview failed". Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you provide more details from the logs.
Error: The file you selected to authenticate (/opt/vsts/work/1/s) is not a valid .npmrc file.
This happened to me today and it was an error on the Build and Release Tasks for Visual Studio Team Services and Team Foundation Server.